# How can I initialize a LinkedList with entries/values in it?

Tags: java, linked-list, initialization

So I know how to have a linked list and use add method to input entries by entries.
However, I do not want to add entries by entries. Is there a way to declare a linkedlist with initial values in the list?

For example, if I want to have 1.0 & 2.0 in the list is there something I can do in one line?
Something like:

```
List<Double> temp1 = new LinkedList<Double>(1,2);
```

Comment: Depends what you want to do with "entries," although it might be a better idea to either use a `Map` or have separate lists for the keys and values.  Putting them together, right next to each other in one list, is really awkward.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: Doesn't sound like the OP wants entries in the sense of map entries... just elements in the list.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I suggested splitting the lists in two.  Certainly if you're adding "related" pairs of elements to the list, it'd make more sense to either wrap them in an object, or split them into two lists.  Certainly there's a solution to the OP's basic question "How can I initialize a list with some specific elements," but the rest of the question sounds like that's maybe not the best approach to the OP's actual problem.

Comment: Oh, I just wanted to have one line of initialization of LinkedList. I knew for int array list, I could do like int[] store = {1,2};
I just did not want to see lines and lines of add methods.

Comment: doesnt work with <String> params

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You can do that this way:

```
List<Double> temp1 = new LinkedList<Double>(Arrays.asList(1.0, 2.0));
```

Answer (score 14):

`LinkedList` has the following constructor, which accepts a parameter of type `Collection`:

```
public LinkedList(Collection<? extends E> c)
```

This constructor 'Constructs a list containing the elements of the specified collection, in the order they are returned by the collection's iterator.'

Therefore you could use this constructor to declare a `LinkedList` and initialize it with values at the time of declaration. You can provide an instance of any `Collection<Double>` type.

If you have only a set of values but not a `Collection` object, then you can use the `java.util.Arrays` class which has the static `asList()` method which will convert the set of values provided to a `List` and return. See the example below:

```
 List<Double> list = new LinkedList<Double>(Arrays.asList(1.2,1.3,3.2));
```

If you need an instance of `List<Double>` then you have to provide the values with a decimal place, otherwise the you'll get an instance of `List<Integer>` with the values.

Answer (score 11):

If you are using JDK9+, you can use `List.of(...)` like:

```
List<Double> myList = new LinkedList<>(List.of(10D, 11D));
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also create method like

```
static <T> LinkedList<T> createLinkedList(T...elements) {
    LinkedList<T> newList = new LinkedList<T>();
    for (T el : elements) {
        newList.add(el);
    }

    return newList;
}
```

And use it with :

```
        LinkedList<Integer> a = createLinkedList(1, 2, 3);

        for (Integer item : a) {
            System.out.println(item);
        }
```